# Add space before capital letters in a dataframe or column in python using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

[image: numbered table of provinces in Afghanistan, columns are Province, Centers, and U.N. Region]

I need to have the values in the columns split up where the capital letters are. So it looks like this:

West Afghanistan or North East Afghanistan

I tried this so far and nothing changes. I would prefer to not go through every column. Is this possible to do without the for loop, possibly using apply_all or lambda, or a combination of the two?

```py
afg_regions['U.N. Region'].replace(('[A-z]','[A-z]*(\s)[A-z]*'),regex=True,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with replace `uppercase` by same vales with space before and then remove first space:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'U.N.Region':['WestAfghanistan','NorthEastAfghanistan']})

df['U.N.Region'] = df['U.N.Region'].str.replace( r"([A-Z])", r" \1").str.strip()
print (df)
                U.N.Region
0         West Afghanistan
1   North East Afghanistan
```

Comment: Good solution, would be a better answer if it explained the problems with the original regex though!

Comment: That's perfect, but is there a way to apply this to the whole dataframe, i.e. all columns? (afg_regions)

Comment: then use `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace( r"([A-Z])", r" \1").str.strip())`

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution:

```
df.apply(lambda col: col.str.replace(r"([a-z])([A-Z])",r"\1 \2"))  

Out: 
              U.N. Region   Centers
0  North East Afghanistan  Fayzabad
1        West Afghanistan  Qala Naw
```

Comment: Beatiful! df=df.apply(lambda col: col.str.replace(r"([a-z])([A-Z])",r"\1 \2"))  did the trick! thank you, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be,

```
import pandas as pd
import re


df = pd.DataFrame({'U.N.Region': ['WestAfghanistan', 'NorthEastAfghanistan']})

df['U.N.Region'] = df['U.N.Region'].str.replace(
    r"(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", " ")
print(df)
```